# insert a div from a page into another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This might seem very easy, however I'm a bit stuck.
I have two pages:
**Page 1**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="guitar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="gridContainer clearfix">
    <div id="Header"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function check() {
            $('#Header').load('ajax/header.html #main_header');
        }
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page 2**

```
<body>
    <div class="gridContainer clearfix">
        <div id="main_header">
            <div id="Logo">
                <img src="files/images/LogoAMKGuitars.png" alt="AMKGuitars">
            </div> 
            <div id="Search_Bar">
                <form action="search.php" method="post" id="search"name="search">
                    <input id="search_field" name="search_field" type="text" placeholder="Search product">    
                    <input id="search_submit" name="search_submit">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="Basket">
                <img src="files/images/viewbasket.png" alt="View Basket">
            </div>
            <div id="Phone">Tel: 0116-2541053</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to put the contents of div `id="main_header` into the Header div on page two. Any help welcome.

Comment: `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+v`

Comment: Assuming the path is correct, what you have should work. The only issue I can see is if you are running on your local file system you will get blocked by the browsers' security. You need to run on a web server - either local or remote

Comment: @Rory Thanls for your reply I am using MAMP. Is there something I can change on my side so it will work on the local as well>

Comment: @orique — Yes it can. Read the docs for load.

Comment: You never actually call the `check` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though you aren't calling the check() function anywhere, something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function check(){
        $('#Header').load('ajax/header.html #main_header');
    }

    $(function() {
        check();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I'm sorry but that didn't work.

Comment: Hmm weird, I have copied the files onto my own local server and it is working. Are you sure your paths are correct? So there is a folder called ajax in the same directory as the page1.html, and a file called header.html in that? Which browser are you using?

Comment: How stupid can I be there was no folder ajax in there so now it is working super. Thanks so much for your patience.